# javascript format hex string to 0x00 and push then to Uint8Array

Tags: javascript

1.- i need a little help to work with hex and format it to 0x00, i have this function to transform decimal or number to hex but the result is in 00 for example 9 to ex => 9 but i need 0x09, or 12 => C but i need 0x0C, i dont know how to format in my desired format.

this is my function:

```html
 public numberToHex(value: number){
    return value.toString(16) as any;
  }

  this.numberToHex(12) ==> logs C but i need 0x0C
```

2.- then i need to add these values to an Uint8Array but when i try to add this to the array i have a error "Type '"0x80"' is not assignable to type 'number'":

example:

```html
getArrayBuffer(){
const data = new Uint8Array(2);
data[0] = this.numberToHex(12); <--- error
data[1] = this.numberToHex(24); <--- error
return data.buffer as ArrayBuffer; 
}
```

any help is appreciated.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A popular trick for zero-padding numbers is to prepend them with `"0"` and call `.slice(-2)` to get the last two digits.

```js
var number = 9;
var padded = "0" + number;
console.log(padded.slice(-2));
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array

> The Uint8Array typed array represents an array of 8-bit unsigned integers

Therefore you should not put strings into it. And if you do those are going to be coerced if possible:

```js
const d = new Uint8Array(4);
d[0] = 9;
d[1] = 0x0C;
d[2] = '9';
d[3] = '0x0C';
console.log(d[0], d[1], d[2], d[3]);
```

Will output:

```
> 9 12 9 12
```

If you need to put the string representation of HEX then parse it before adding into array:

```js
const parsed = parseInt('c', 16);
const d = new Uint8Array(1);
d[0] = parsed;
console.log(d);
```

Will output:

```
> Uint8Array [ 12 ]
```

Comment: yes, thanks i found i just has to parseInt the result with the 0x, with the answer above i only have to conver the number to hex with the function and then parseInt('0x'+this.numberToHex(12).slice(-2)) --> 0x0c string and 12 in number.

Comment: `parseInt('0x'+this.numberToHex(12).slice(-2), 16)` and `parseInt(this.numberToHex(12), 16)` produce the same result